# How would I write "Hermit Farm" in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

My wife and I have built a forever home on 25 acres just outside a small country town (population approximately 8000) in Australia. We have joked over the years that we are doing this because we are hermits or reclusive. I would like to have the property signposted as "Hermit Farm" in Latin, probably in the form of a farm that produces hermits, as a farm might produce wheat or pigs. So far the best fit seems to be "*Villa Eremita*" or "*Eremita Agellus*", but the former seems to suggest a grand country estate, whereas the latter just a small field. I'm tending towards the former as it is more recognisable, but could anyone suggest which would be the best translation or perhaps a better alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Eremita* is correct for hermit, and the most appropriate word for farm is *fundus*. You need to use a possessive after 'farm', as in 'Farm of Hermits', which gives us *Fundus Eremitarum*.

*Villa Eremitarum* would be fine, but is very posh.

[Orwell's novella Animal Farm has similarly been translated as *Fundus Animalium*.]

Comment: Tom, thank you very much for that answer - its perfect. Having the Latin title of Animal Farm to uses as a reference to cite to curious friends is a fantastic bonus too. I note you are the author of that and other books, which is just amazing to me, so we'll put a little acknowledgement on our sign of your authorship.